# How to display the form submission results in a custom page?

Tags: views, webforms, 7

How to display the form submission results in a custom page or a view ?

I want to display it in a custom style with table , and want to do custom php coding too .

where i have to create custom page , or is there need a custom module for this ??

Comment: Refer to link [LINK1](http://yalesites.yale.edu/book/creating-view-webform-data) & [LINK2](https://www.drupal.org/node/1658784). Try to use any of these links. Hope your issue might be solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Display Webform Submission Data using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/1658784) is a bit challenging. As an alternative to installing [Webform MySQL Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) (which depends on [Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) and [Schema](https://www.drupal.org/project/schema)), consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) module. Here is a quote about it:

> ... built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.

So in this case you'd use Forena to report about the Webform data stored in the Webform tables, which are contained in your Drupal database.

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).